# Ruby on Rails console returns text I enter for one word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I had a database table called Distributor.
I deleted the database and have no tables. Now when I go to the console and type in anything it returns NameError which is perfect.

But when I type in `Distributor` it returns `=>Distributor` 
Why isn't it returning a NameError? What is it returning? Did I not clear something?

```
2.1.0 :004 > Distributor
=> Distributor 
2.1.0 :005 > Distributor.destroy
NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for Distributor:Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you restart the console/server? The class might be cached. Hate to tell you this, but... try turning it off and back on again.

EDIT: Classes and Modules are defined in your codebase. Classes that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base will expect to see a matching table, but the matching tables don't *have* to exist. Typing `Distributor` will still return fine without errors, even if the database isn't there.

Comment: I tried this. It does show up as a module if I try a method with it.

Comment: It does look like you have a Distributor module defined somewhere. Or it's still cached. Maybe if you're running a brand new Rails application, spring could be running. Try running `spring stop`?

Comment: I don't have spring installed. The app is new. I just want to start the db from scratch now.

Comment: Extended my answer. Even if your database is completely gone, if the class or module is defined in your codebase, Rails will load without problems, and you'll still be able to see them.

Comment: Okay, well I guess that answers the question. When I migrated another table it wasn't found in the console.